# Load balancing and Fail-over at the same time on Cisco Router

Tags: networking, cisco, load-balancing, router, failover

is there a method to have both Load balancing and Fail-over at the same time on Cisco Router which has 2 connections to 2 different ISPs ?

As my understanding, Load balancing is Active-Active whereas Fail-over is Active-Standby, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

We deployed two Cisco ISRs with BGP for ISP independent failover. Our original intention was that we would make the ISRs into an active-passive pair and have BGP for ISP failover. Our vendor pointed out that such a configuration is a bit unnecessary because all four routers (our two ISRs and the router from each ISP) can use BGP to adjust routing in the event of the failure of any one of them.

So we just picked one of the ISRs to be a higher cost path to our network and one of the ISPs to be a higher cost path to the Internet, and BGP takes care of the rest.

Comment: Hi, how about the route-map and IP-SLA combination? I found some articles on the Internet but feel a bit confuse because of their difference.

Comment: I followed these 2 links in this morning: http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/813-cisco-router-ipsla-basic.html, and http://netsyshorizon.blogspot.com/2015/03/cisco-router-wan-redundancy-dual-failover.html, but seems like we can have only one mechanism at the same time. The links provided Active-Standby method